# How to decorate classes, methods and properties with attributes in Progress Openedge ABL with .NET bridge?

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, progress-4gl, openedge

I have to use Progress Openedge Architect in my work, and I need to convert some C# code to ABL code (ABL is the language name). So I need to find how to decorate my classes, properties and methods with .NET attributes. I searched through this guide ( http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge102b/pdfs/dvngm/dvngm.pdf ) but there is no mention about decoration in the C# to ABL mapping section.

A simple C# example:

```
[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("9.75")]
public decimal POLICE {
    get {
        return ((decimal)(this["POLICE"]));
    }
    set {
        this["POLICE"] = value;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help on this!

Kind regards,

Gabriel

Answer (score 1):

It is **not** possible use the attributes from C# in ABL code. You can create instances from the C# class or inherit it.

In this case I would make this attributes in C# code. Then I would inherit this class in ABL and make some wrappers, when is necessary.

Until 10.2B is allowed to use this C# classes **only** on client side (program must running on prowin32.exe)...

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good place to ask that question: http://communities.progress.com/pcom/community/psdn/openedge/gui4dotnet?view=discussions

Comment: Did that. It is apparently not possible out of the box. I'll close the question when I'll be sure it's impossible.